# Error in building R from source in Windows (Error 1 and 2)

Tags: r, compiler-errors, openblas

I'm trying to build R from source in Windows to be able to use openBLAS (following suggestions http://www.avrahamadler.com/2013/10/24/an-openblas-based-rblas-for-windows-64-step-by-step/ ) to improve speed but I receive the following error during make all:

```
gcc -std=gnu99   -I../include -I. -I../extra -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DR_DLL_BUILD  -c -o e_pow.o e_pow.S
e_pow.S: Assembler messages:
e_pow.S:110: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
e_pow.S:111: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
e_pow.S:227: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
e_pow.S:228: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
e_pow.S:278: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
e_pow.S:279: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
e_pow.S:313: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
e_pow.S:314: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
make[3]: *** [e_pow.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [../../bin/i386/R.dll] Error 2
make[1]: *** [rbuild] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't figure it out what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are building 32-bit R. My instructions are for 64-bit only; sorry.